# Help with adding GMap on contact page

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to add a GMap to my contact page, I don't have the need for Location / GMap modules. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) but following it I have to add everything to the head in my html.tpl file:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Where else can I place this script? I've tried to add it in a separate JS file and call it through my info file but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have miss something.

For Gmap on Drupal site there are many ways to implement.

You can try this approch:

- Put whole the code in any block with full text format.
- Place that block in a specific region.
- Set visiblity of that bock as per your requirment.

Implementation code be like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rupesh 22, that works fine. But is that the best way to implement it or should I be looking at creating a small custom module to do this? Just want to know best practices. Thanks

Comment: @TMardi There are not any bad thing to use this approch.